# UITextField delegate not working, once everything was working

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Once everything was working, but now everything seems to be same, but my uitextfield delegate not working.

My UITextfield is inside of the xib, and i am adding this textfield to my viewcontroller and set my viewcontroller as the delegate of my textfield.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong or what might be changed?

My code is as follows,

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CreditCardApplyViews" bundle:nil];
creditCardApplyLastStepView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:2];

[creditCardApplyLastStepView.tcknTextField setDelegate:self];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.gsmTextField setDelegate:self];


int counter = 0;

if(cardItem.firstDescription !=nil)
    counter++;
if(cardItem.secondDescription !=nil)
    counter++;
if(cardItem.thirdDescription !=nil)
    counter++;
if(cardItem.fourthDescription !=nil)
    counter++;
if(cardItem.fifthDescription !=nil)
    counter++;

[creditCardApplyLastStepView.descriptionScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(230*counter, 0)];

CGRect frame = creditCardApplyLastStepView.frame;
frame.origin.y+=48;
creditCardApplyLastStepView.frame = frame;

creditCardApplyLastStepView.creditCardApplyItem = cardItem;



[creditCardApplyLastStepView.cardImageView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
//[creditCardApplyLastStepView.applyButton.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

[creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint2.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint3.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint4.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint5.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

[creditCardApplyLastStepView.tcknTextField becomeFirstResponder];

[creditCardApplyLastStepView.closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(alertButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.applyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(applyButtonOnLastStepPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[creditCardApplyLastStepView.cardImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:cardItem.cardImage]];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.cardTitle setText:cardItem.cardTitle];


[creditCardApplyLastStepView.firstDescriptionTextView setText:cardItem.firstDescription];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.secondDescriptionTextView setText:cardItem.secondDescription];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView.thirdDescriptionTextView setText:cardItem.thirdDescription];

if(cardItem.fourthDescription == nil)
{
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.fourthDescriptionTextView setHidden:YES];
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint4 setHidden:YES];
}
else
{
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint4 setHidden:NO];
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.fourthDescriptionTextView setHidden:NO];
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.fourthDescriptionTextView setText:cardItem.fourthDescription];

}

if(cardItem.fifthDescription == nil)
{
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint5 setHidden:YES];
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.fifthDescriptionTextView setHidden:YES];
}
else
{
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.bluePoint5 setHidden:NO];
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.fifthDescriptionTextView setHidden:NO];
    [creditCardApplyLastStepView.fifthDescriptionTextView setText:cardItem.fifthDescription];

}

[self.view addSubview:creditCardApplyLastStepView];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:)name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:creditCardApplyLastStepView.gsmTextField];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:)name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:creditCardApplyLastStepView.tcknTextField];


[self createTextFieldValidationView:creditCardApplyLastStepView.tcknTextField];
[self createTextFieldValidationView:creditCardApplyLastStepView.gsmTextField];

[creditCardApplyLastStepView addSubview:textFieldValidationViewOfTCKN];
[creditCardApplyLastStepView addSubview:textFieldValidationViewOfGSM];
```

Same lines of code in the backup project works fine but the one above does not.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stupid suggestion but did you forget to put  <UITextFieldDelegate> in your VC

Comment: @NewEngland i have already done it